# Failing to use User object as parameter for ? extends User in Java generics

Tags: java, generics

I have trouble using generics. Firstly I've declared

```
public class SymmetricIndexedRealMatrix<T> implements iIndexedMatrix<T,T, Double>{
    public Double getElement(T rowObject, T columnObject) { ... }
}
```

then

```
public class CRF<U> {
    private SymmetricIndexedRealMatrix<U> binaryEnergy;
    private Set<U> labelSet;
    public SymmetricIndexedRealMatrix<U> getBinaryEnergy() {
        return binaryEnergy;
    }
    public Set<U> getLabelSet() {
        return labelSet;
}
    ...
}
```

then I use such part of code

```
CRF<? extends User> crf = new CRF<User>(sourceGraph, targetGraph.getElements(User.class), getUnaryEnergyComputer(), getBinaryEnergyComputer()
...
for (User targetUser1 : crf.getLabelSet()) {
    for (User targetUser2 : crf.getLabelSet()) {
        System.out.print(crf.getBinaryEnergy().getElement(targetUser1, targetUser2) + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

and it results in compilation error:

> The method getElement(capture#10-of ? extends User, capture#10-of ? extends User) in the type SymmetricIndexedRealMatrix is not applicable for the arguments (User, User)

What's wrong and how should it be fixed?

Comment: What's the type of `crf.getBinaryEnergy()`?

Comment: @Eran added to code block. Also I've made a mistake with posting type of indexed matrix. Now it's correct here.

Comment: What's this `Node` you have in your compilation error message? I see no Node in your code.

Comment: @Eran oh, my carelessness again, changed to correct error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you have 2 sub-classes that extend `User` - `SubUser1` and `SubUser2`.

The following code is possible :

```
CRF<? extends User> crf = new CRF<SubUser1>(...);
User targetUser1 = new SubUser2();
User targetUser2 = new SubUser2();
```

Now, if you try to call `crf.getBinaryEnergy().getElement(targetUser1, targetUser2)`, as you did, it won't work since the specific instance assigned to `crf` expects `SubUser1` users, not `SubUser2`.

Even though in your actual code you used only `User` types (and no sub-classes), the compiler has no way of knowing the exact type of the instance that would be assigned to `crf` in runtime, which is why your code doesn't compile.

```
CRF<User> crf = new CRF<User> (...);
```

will solve the error.

Comment: I tried to fix the problem in the way, you've advised, but nothung changed, I still get exactly the same error message.

Comment: @ЯрославБондарчук How's `SymmetricIndexedRealMatrix` defined?

Comment: Also, as I understand it, when I create CRF object parametrized with User symmetric matrix is created and parametrized with the same type. Then I use getElement(SubUser1 u1, SubUser u2) method and u1 and u2 are treated as object of Users, so the type of their Subclasses shouldn't matter. Where am I wrong?

Comment: again my mistake, changed code block. And if it is important I use `CRF<? extends User> crf` or `CRF<User> crf` as a field in another class, and in constructor I use crf = new CRF<User> (...)

Comment: Thank you! It's work now - the problem was in fact, that in code it was not `crf.getBinaryEnergy()` but `uir.getCRF().getBinaryEnergy()` and in class `UIR` method `CRF<? extends User> getCRF(){..}`. Changing this method to `CRF<User> getCRF()` helped, so your advice was good, but previously I failed to find exact place to change parametrization of `CRF<>`.

Answer (score 1):

Just declare `crf` as having type `CRF<User>`; or, if you really need a wildcard type, `CRF<? super User>`.

Remember the acroynm PECS - producer extends, consumer super. You are passing a `User` into a method on the `Matrix`, so that matrix is *consuming* your value. Its type needs to be compatible with `Matrix<? super User>`, so `crf` needs to be `CRF<? super User>` also. `CRF<User>` is a subtype of `CRF<? super User>`.

Comment: It can be `<User>`, that is in `<? super User>` - and using the type without the wildcard is the simplest option. I've reworded my answer slightly.